# Ability to apply specific tinylog writer

Tags: java, logging, logback, tinylog

As a developer I want to have an ability to implicitly or explicitly call particular writer, not all of them. Similar to how logback's name property works. It allows you to assign particular logger(class) to particular appender e.g.

Is it be possible to achieve it in tinylog2?